# javascript shifting >32-bit to get 64-bit Int

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I am using an `API` which `responseType` is `ArrayBuffer`. so for reading data from is i am using `DataView`. which allows me to read 32-bit Int max and in float its 64-bit for which i can get max of 53-bit int.

have some int values of 6-byte. so for reading or writing > 32-bit Int i needed bit shifting of `>=32-bit`. but the following link says JavaScript shift operation works for `<32-bit`. here is the link [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

how can I read a 6-byte or 8-byte int from `DataView` in JavaScript via shifting or any means?

Comment: Not really sure, but you might want to look into https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js for those larger than life numbers.

Comment: ya i already looked at that one. its does not include any api for bit level operation. so it will be work like javascript

Comment: Have you tried it out with base 2? if you provide the data as bits in base 2 it should convert fine to a BigInt object on which you can do your integer caluclations. Then if its smaller than 32 bits you can export it to a javascript int on which you can do bitwise shifts. You can always modify the libary to suit your needs. Just look at how they do it and change it where needed to support bit shifting.